# Cells with formulas do not evaluate in Excel 2010

Tags: excel

So I created a new sheet and pasted a big table of CSV into it.
Then I used "Text To Columns" and changed all columns to "Text".

Now I've got a strange problem.
I inserted a column in the middle of the data then I entered a formula, like:

```
=K1 + 2
```

But instead of displaying the results excel displays the formula.
If I hit "F2" to edit, cell "K1" is NOT highlighted as a source.
It acts sort of like I typed in a quoted string instead of a formula.

I know about "Ctrl + `" to show/hide formulas -- that isn't it.

Copy-n-pasting a cell with a formula like "=1+2" from a different sheet into a broken cell fixes it.
Pasting plain-text (like, from notepad) into a cell doesn't fix it.

Changing the Number format from "Text" to "Number" appears to do nothing, but then if I edit the cell without making changes fixes the problem (e.g F2 followed by enter).

Normally, changing a cell to "Text" using the "Number" menu doesn't make the cell stick so firmly in text mode.

Is there a way to toggle a cell in and out of this without using "Text to columns" ?

Comment: So after you use `Text To Columns`, what is the type of the cells?  `General` or `Text`? Also how is your CSV delimited?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I inserted a column in the middle of the data then I entered a formula

**After** you have inserted the column and **before** you enter the formula, you should format the cells in the column to General.  The inserted column starts out in Text format and must be fixed.

**EDIT**:

Here is the macro.....select the cells having the formulas entered as text and run it:

```
Sub FixFormula()
    Dim r As Range, s As String
    For Each r In Selection
        s = r.Text
        r.Clear
        r.Formula = s
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but isn't really the answer I'm looking for. Text-to-cols seems to put cell into a bit of a mystery mode - a very sticky "Text" state. This state doesn't seem to be displayed anywhere and until I figured out what was happening it was really confusing. So, I've got the work-around, and now I'm just looking to better understand whats going on in Excels little mind here.

Comment: Using a tiny macro, you can "fix" formulas entered as text.  Are you O.K. with a macro solution??

Comment: Hm... OK, So I guess I'm wrong.
Setting a cell to "Text" does behave the same .... odd that I've never noticed that before.
Experiment: Set a blank cell to "Text". Now, enter "=1+2". It displays the formula instead of "3". Change the cell type to "Number". It still displays "=1+2"!

Comment: Sure, what does the macro look like?

Comment: Selecting the dell and pressing "Delete" worked for me.